# JSON.parse changes large numeric values

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, buffer

I am using MQTT to transport messages to a server. I receive a payload with a numeric id **2898871460539924579** yet by the time it gets pumped into my database it has become **2898871460539924500**.

I have traced the problem to JSON.parse(). I took the Buffer object that gets passed by MQTT, which I then convert to a string using `dataBuffer.toString()`. This shows me the correct id (*2898871460539924579*). When I then run `JSON.parse(dataBuffer.toString())`, that number is changed to being *2898871460539924500*.

If you look at the two numbers side-by-side you'll see that they are almost exactly identical, but for the last two digits:

```
289 887 146 053 992 45 79
289 887 146 053 992 45 00
```

This is the same for all the numerical IDs (of this size) that get passed into the system. Is there a way to get `JSON.parse()` to correctly parse these numbers?

**EDIT**

[This post about large integers in javascript](http://www.2ality.com/2012/07/large-integers.html) seems to be very relevant to this problem.

Comment: by the way, JSON.parse has nothing to do with it - alert(2898871460539924579)

Comment: Yes, @JaromandaX: discovered max limits on javascript representation of ints, so am now passing strings instead.